# Charging a LiFePo4 12v 40ah battery with 10A charger instead of 6A

Tags: current, lifepo4

I purchased a Bioenno Battery with 12v 40ah.
I already have a 10A LiFePo4 battery charger.

The new battery says charging current should be 6A.
Can I charge it with a 10A charger since it has a built in PCB/BMS?
Seems like you would have to have a charger for each type of battery otherwise.

[Data sheet?](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0219/0154/files/BLF-1240A_User_Manual_rev_04_23_2019.pdf?209)

UPDATE 20 Jan 2020:

I emailed Bienno and asked them the same question (since the Battery and the charger are both theirs).

Their response was "That's fine."

Comment: 0.15C maximum charge rate seems awfully low. I thought you could charge LiFe batteries at 4C or even 5C. Are you sure it says the battery can be charged at 6A and not 6C? Maybe that 6A has more to do with the BMS than the battery itself. But I don't think a BMS would be able to dissipate the extra 4A. That's a lot of heat.

Comment: Link the battery datasheet in the question.

Comment: I find that batteru spec 'suspect'. It may be OK and they are ding something 'clever' - perhaps to increase lifetime. The 6A/40Ah = 0.15C charge rate is exceptionally low.

Comment: There seem to be no adverse comments on their products with a few minutes searching. They are VERY keen at maintaining closed-shop 'must use our chargers' . Technically this should not be needed but its up to you. 10A max into a 40 Ah LiFePO4 SOUNDS extremely conservative - but they may even have internal charge current detection that the battery reacts to.

Comment: As the 6A figure is mentioned several times in the dathasheet, it must be part of their design. It may very well be enforced in the BMS. So, not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

[Do not exceed the spec.](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0219/0154/files/BLF-1240A_User_Manual_rev_04_23_2019.pdf?209)

They must have had some reason for discontinuing a [10A charger offer on Amazon](https://www.amazon.ca/Bioenno-Power-40Ah-Battery-BLF-1240WS/dp/B01DOXYKXM).